# How to launch an activity of another app that's from a library?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-library

So I have 2 apps. Let's say I'm in app A, and I know that there is app B and that it is using library C. Library C has an activity that i want to launch from app A. How can I do that?

EDIT: Actually, both A and B apps are using the same library. But my goal is to launch an activity of the another app.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in **Kotlin**:

```
fun runDifferentActivity() {
    // Different app package
    val otherAppPackage = "comp.package.android.something.there"
    // Activity name (from different App)
    val otherAppActivity = "SecretActivity"

    val action = "$otherAppPackage.$otherAppActivity"

    // Create Intent with action name
    val intent = Intent(action)

    // Start activity
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

**or in Java:**

```
void runDifferentActivity() {
    // Different app package
    String otherAppPackage = "comp.package.android.something.there";

    // Activity name (from different App)
    String otherAppActivity = "SecretActivity";

    String action = String.format("%s.%s", otherAppPackage, otherAppActivity);

    // Create Intent with action name
    Intent intent = new Intent(action);

    // Start activity
    startActivity(intent);
}
```